# "Не" с разными частями речи

Tags: орфография

Как написать с не:
(не)досчитаешься друзей (здесь приставка до или недо?),

вышла замуж (не)любя (здесь ведь явно не деепричастие, а наречие)?

Answer (score 3):

**1) НЕДОСЧИТАТЬСЯ,** - Обнаружить недостаток, отсутствие кого-, чего-л., при счёте, подсчёте. Н. двух овец. Н. трёх рублей.

Здесь **приставка НЕДО** со значением недостаточности, например: Из экипажа «Светланы» **недосчитались** ста шестидесяти семи человек. [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Цусима (1932-1935)]

Но у Пушкина (сохранена орфография):

Я пью один, и на брегах Невы
Меня друзья сегодня именуют…
Но многие ль и там из вас пируют?
Еще кого **не досчитались** вы?

**2) Вышла замуж не любя.** Деепричастие употребляется в значении наречия, но сохраняет раздельную форму написания НЕ.

**Другие примеры**: рассердиться не шутя (всерьёз), идти не спеша (тихо), ехать не торопясь (медленно),  отправиться не мешкая (сейчас же), жить ни с кем не знакомясь (замкнуто), выйти замуж не любя (без любви).